# casting to matrix apparently has no effect

Tags: r

How do I correctly convert `struc` to a matrix so I can run the lines below on it?

my input is the dataframe `scaled_data`

```
library('psych')
res<-fa(r=cor(scaled_data), nfactors=26, rotate="promax", SMC=FALSE, fm="minres")
struc  <- as.matrix(res$Structure)
struc2 <- ifelse(struc <= 0.7, NA, struc)
class(struc)
# [1] "loadings"
class(struc2)
# [1] "matrix"
```

for more context I am trying to run these lines on it. struc2 works perfectly, but has the NA's (which I expected) and am trying to not have.

```
#create individual person scores for all factors
###################################################
temp<-cbind(scaled_data, apply(struc, 2, function(x) rowMeans(scaled_data[,!is.na(x),drop=FALSE])))
start_subscales<-length(grep("^[a-z]",colnames(temp)))+1
subscale_scores<-temp[,start_subscales:ncol(temp)] #get only v1...v22 scores
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: the class of `struc` is not a matrix, when I explicitly cast it as one, and I cant figure out why it isn't......This may explain some really weird code output later on

Comment: you can use `class(tmp) <- 'matrix'`. Since `is.matrix(struc)` is TRUE, as.matrix doesn't do anything. the class of struc is loadings because the people who wrote the psych package wanted that class to print a certain way, but it was always a matrix

Comment: That returns the correct result, but the code beneath it is still wrong..... I will try to come up with a reproducible example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"matrix" is an implicit class, so it won't show up if an object has an explicit class defined:

```
x <- matrix(1:9, 3)
class(x) <- "boogey"
class(x)
# [1] "boogey"
is.matrix(x)
# [1] TRUE
class(x) <- NULL
class(x)
# [1] "matrix"
```